# Webhook does not return JSON

Tags: json, http, webhooks

When performing a GET Request on my Webhook (after triggering it) it returns the following response:

```
{
"id": "09292225-474a-408f-ab9d-ea2bc66e7fc4",
"request_id": "5f71ac28-98ff-4a01-b542-74ef3b21b700",
"attempt": "5f71ac28-98ff-4a01-b542-74ef3b21b700",
"status": "success"
}
```

but as I understand, it should be returning the JSON informations of the triggering event (like name, email, username ...)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct response - it's Zapier informing you that your webhook was received. Since task execution happens asynchronously on Zapier, further info cannot be returned about the result of the webhook.